# Facing error: Cannot perform web service invocation

Tags: wsdl, coldfusion-2016, coldfusion-7

I am moving an old client application running on CF MX7 server to their newer CF 2016 Server.
One of the page in this application is calling a wsdl service to get some data.

After moving the code to CF2016 server, I am getting the below error:

Cannot perform web service invocation WWS001Operation.

Below is the part from the code where the service is called:

```
    <cfscript>
     //Printer validation
     printername = structNew() ;
    
     printername.pid = "1221";
    
     printername.command = "PRINTERS"&#url.branch_loc#;
    
     ws = createObject("webservice", "http://*serviceurl*:9117/wsdl/WWS001.wsdl");
    
     printerdtls  = ws.WWS001Operation(printername);
    
     printerdtlsreq  = printerdtls.TABLEOUT;
     isprntrvalid="no";
     for(i=1;i LTE ArrayLen(printerdtlsreq);i=i+1)
     {
      tempprntrData = UCase(printerdtlsreq[i].TNAME);
      //writeOutput(tempprntrData & "<bR />");
    
     }
     //writeoutput(#ArrayLen(printer`enter code here`dtlsreq)#);
     //END
    </cfscript>
```

Tried updating the webservice version to 1 in the CF Administrator which did not help.
Is there anything which is no longer supported in newer 2016 version and if the code needs any update to make is run in 2016?